# I want to get the file in response stream after long period of time

Tags: java, csv, servlets, transactions

I have internal tool which will show the results by pulling it from DB  for 100k records

At one occasion I have to do web service call for each record(I can't store it in DB as  there is a security issue),

Please find my design below,

Step1:
User clicks the button(get file)

Step2:
I am calling the DB and we service  with use of thread and thread pool
 and writing into the  CSV file
It taking 5 mins to process as I have 100k web service call,

Step3:
Once the step 2 done I have to read CSV the file and will write into bytearrayoutputstream ,
Set the response content type as (text /csv),

I will  write those into response which will download the csv files into user system.

Issue:

I am getting proxy server issue as it taking more than 5 mins,

I am getting Http session time out or 502 invalid response.

Any suggestions to give files to  user ?

Please help me to resolve this issue if you can.

p.s as it is internal tool user ready to wait  more than five mins  to get the file
 I can't change the step 1  and step 2.

Comment: think is I am getting timeout

Comment: if you're networking that means it's in a try block. Are you printing the stack trace for any exception that may be shown to see the error?

Comment: In UI am getting proxy error 502 but backend processing is going on